# Como escribir objetos dinamicos a un archivo JSON en Python

Tags: python

Nescecito escribir objectos a un archivo JSON, partiendo de una estructura basica.

```
proyectname: {
  "author": author
}
```

para que cuando se ejecute el codigo el archivo JSON quede algo como asi:

```
{"casa": {"author": "Pedro"},"carro": {"author": "Andres"}}
```

como yo lo he intentado siempre queda algo mal y queda algo asi

```
{"casa": {"author": "Pedro"},{"carro": {"author": "Andres"}}
```

el codigo que estoy empleando es el siguiente

```
proyectname = input('¿Como es el nombre del proyecto?' )
author = input('¿Quien hizo este proyecto?' )

    data = {
        proyectname: {
          "author": author
        }
     }
    
        with open(f'data.json', 'r') as r:
                    jsondata = r.read()
        with open('data.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
            jsonfile.write(jsondata[:-1])
            jsonfile.write(',')
            json.dump(data, jsonfile)
```

Agradeceria que me pudieran brindar su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve tu mismo problema, pero la verdad es que es muy sencillo! Lo que debes hacer es pasar el archivo JSON a un diccionario de python con *json.load()*, y ahí sí que vas a poder modificar el diccionario, posteriormente a esto tendrás que usar la función *dump* que ví que usaste en tu código, pero para adjuntar el diccionario que hiciste desde python. Te quedará algo así:

```
import json

proyectname = input('¿Como es el nombre del proyecto?' )
author = input('¿Quien hizo este proyecto?' )

with open('stacky.json', 'r') as f:
    x = json.load(f)

x[proyectname] = {"author": author}

with open('stacky.json', 'w') as outcome:
    json.dump(x, outcome, indent=2)
```

PD: Lo de *indent=2* no es necesario, es solo para que el archivo este más organizado, espero te haya ayudado!